# Loading an image?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have list box where I need to display image from the internet

I have a data-source like this:

[image]

and I bind "image" in listbox using `DataTemplate` like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Image Source="{Binding image}"></Image>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding imagedec}"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

I am able to see the image but it comes late, what will be best way to display images in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the image has to be loaded from the internet (or cache) first. Try adding a gray background as placeholder and set a fixed height and width:

```
<Border Background="{StaticResource PhoneInactiveBrush}" Width="100" Height="100">
    <Image Source="{Binding image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="100" Height="100" />
</Border>
```

This solution works only if you can set a fixed height and width...

UPDATE

You should use `LowProfileImageLoader` to improve performance: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/09/02/keep-a-low-profile-lowprofileimageloader-helps-the-windows-phone-7-ui-thread-stay-responsive-by-loading-images-in-the-background.aspx

Comment: I know , they are loading from internet :D , so this is best solution so far? we have to wait until image is not display or something like Asynchronous data/image loading !! , i am not sure :(

Comment: If you set the image it will be loaded asynchronously. You have to take into account that the loading of the image over the internat may takes a while. But it is also possible to load the images to a cache (local storage) and bind the image to this cache... This way you could load the images in the previous page and show it faster in the next page... But this solution is a lot more time-consuming to implement...